# Change ng-src on {{bind}} in context

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working with Ionic and Angular. I have a repeat within a repeat, like below. It outputs a main (large) image, and multiple extra's (smaller) images below it.

```
<div class="list card" ng-model="tweet" ng-repeat="text in tweet">

  <div class="item item-avatar">
    <img ng-src="{{text.profileImage}}">
    <h2>@{{text.screen_name}}</h2>
    <p>{{correctTimestring(text.timeAt) | date:'medium'}}</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item item-body">
    <img src="{{ newImage || text.image[0].imageurl }}" class="full-image">

    <div ng-model="image" ng-repeat="data in text.image">
      <div class="item item-avatar">
        <img src="{{data.imageurl}}" class="miniImage">
      </div>
    </div>

    <p>
      {{text.text}}
    </p>
    <p>
      <a class="item item-icon-left assertive" href="#">
        <i class="icon ion-social-twitter-outline"></i> Open Link
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Which pulls and creates multiple tiles like so:

[image]

I would like to be able to click on the lower (smaller photos) to replace the top image, to "scroll through them".

How can I achieve this with Angular, updating the $scope.newImage just replaces all the images. How can I just replace the main image above the smaller images below it?

Any help is appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Ok. This line is a nonsense `<div ng-model="image" ng-repeat="data in text.image">`.
Why you have a `ng-model` in a `<div>` with a `ng-repeat`? The @Seba answer is right

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new property: "$scope.selectedImage" and a function that allow you select the image (setSelectedImage). So:

Change this:

```
 <img src="{{ newImage || text.image[0].imageurl }}" class="full-image">
```

with:

```
  <img src="{{ newImage || selectedImage.imageurl }}" class="full-image">
```

and add ng-click here:

```
<div class="item item-avatar">
    <img src="{{data.imageurl}}" class="miniImage" ng-click="setSelectedImage(data)">
</div>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.selectedImage;

$scope.setSelectedImage(data){
    // Always one image is selected
    $scope.selectedImage = data;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this replace all the repeated {{ selectedImage.imageurl }} images if there were multiple tiles?